# WooCommerce reviews/comments in different languages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

My shop has 8 languages.
We have comments in Dutch, English, German, French for our products. For the other languages we don't have that much reviews. This is fine.

I have created a seperate page to display the reviews for each language. So I created a review page for Dutch, English, German, French, Danish, Swedish, Hungarian and Polish. Then I display the reviews for each language on their review page.
Here is the code to do this:

```
<div class="commentlist">
        <?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl'):
            $args = array ('post_id' => 287, 'order' => ASC);
            $comments = get_comments( $args );
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments); ?>
        <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'):
            $args = array ('post_id' => 1521, 'order' => ASC);
            $comments = get_comments( $args );
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments); ?>
        <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='de'):
            $args = array ('post_id' => 1828, 'order' => ASC);
            $comments = get_comments( $args );
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments); ?>
        <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr'):
            $args = array ('post_id' => 2354, 'order' => ASC);
            $comments = get_comments( $args );
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments); ?>
        <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='sv'):
            $args = array ('post_id' => 1521, 'order' => ASC);
            $comments = get_comments( $args );
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments); ?>
        <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='da'):
            $args = array ('post_id' => 1521, 'order' => ASC);
            $comments = get_comments( $args );
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments); ?>
        <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='pl'):
            $args = array ('post_id' => 1521, 'order' => ASC);
            $comments = get_comments( $args );
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments); ?>
        <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='hu'):
            $args = array ('post_id' => 287, 'order' => ASC);
            $comments = get_comments( $args );
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>         
    </div>
```

As you can see, I want the english reviews on the hungarian, polish, swedish and danish page. So I use the post-id of the English product containing the reviews. But this is not working.
Probably because these languages don't have a product with post-id .

For some reason it should be possible to retrieve the english reviews on the hungarian, Polish, Swedish and Danish review page.

Anybody an idea?

Regards,
Roland

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55210 may help your question

Comment: Hi Illya,
Tried that but didn't worked. Couldn't get the reviews from the other languages.

Comment: "not working" - what are you observing, exactly? Same comments always returning? Zero results? And why hardcode the ID? Do you only have 1 product?

Comment: "Not working" means no output for the 'other languages' like da, pl, sv to output the english comments. Probably because this ID does not exist in that language.

The reason for hardcoded ID is simple. I only want to output the reviews from 1 single product. This ID will never change.